# How do I prevent any other process from writing to a file while reading from it in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

### Background

In my C program, I am reading from a file line by line.

```
FILE *file = fopen("config.txt", "r");

if (file)
{
    char *line;
    size_t length;
    size_t read;
    int test_case_number = 0;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &length, file)) != -1)
    {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
}
else
{
    fputs("The provided <PATH_TO_CONFIG FILE> does not exist.\n\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

### Issue

However, while I am reading this file, I want to prevent any other process from writing to `config.txt` while its being read. How can I do this?

Comment: Check out the man page for `flock()`.

Comment: @LSerni I have, but I am not sure if `flock()` will work with `fopen()`

Comment: You want *mandatory* file locking then. That depends on a lot of things. What is your platform?

Comment: Standard C doesn't provide a mechanism for preventing concurrent readers and writers.  POSIX provides voluntary mechanisms such as [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) and [`lockf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lockf.html) but if the writing process doesn't test for a lock, there's not much the reader can do.  Some systems provide mandatory locking with a special `chmod()` mode on a file but many do not.

Comment: @LSerni Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Some POSIX-like systems use the IS_SGID bit on non-executable files to indicate mandatory file locking.  That was provided by SVID (System V Interface Definition).  POSIX does not mandate mandatory locking — it does mention it in the rationale for  [`chmod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chmod.html).  Also note that POSIX does not standardize `flock()` — it has `lockf()` and `fcntl()` which is quite enough.  Nevertheless, `flock()` is widely available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to "defend" against your own processes or "well behaved" processes, then you want to use `flock`:

```
   fp = fopen(fileName, fileMode);
   if (fp != NULL) {
       flock(fileno(fp), LOCK_EX);
       ...
       fclose(fp); fp = NULL;
   }
```

But those locks are *advisory* only, that is, any other process can **choose to ignore them**. Or not bother checking. I've just tried creating a file, opening it and locking with LOCK_EX, then sleeping for 60 seconds. During that time, another process was free to do whatever it wanted to the file (Linux, Ubuntu 18.04-LTS).

But if you need *mandatory* locking, that's not something that is available on all platforms since the kernel has to cooperate. [Here](https://gavv.github.io/articles/file-locks/) you will find a description and example on how the *limited* mandatory lock support in Linux can be used.

On the other hand, in Windows this is automatic:

> Windows defaults to automatic, mandatory file locking. UNIXes default to manual,
>   cooperative file locking. In both cases, the defaults can be overridden, but in both
>   cases they usually aren’t. ([source](https://www.howtogeek.com/141393/why-cant-i-alter-in-use-files-on-windows-like-i-can-on-linux-and-os-x/)).

A **workaround** can be to temporarily rename the file being worked on to a unique name, possibly creating an empty file with the old name in its place, then renaming it back once you've done; or copying the file as above, leaving a copy for other programs to read. Write denial can also be achieved by changing the file permissions. These solutions require to handle some edge cases, e.g. where your process crashes or the machine hangs before setting things back as they were.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, you can use [flock()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) (focus by me):

> Apply or remove an advisory lock on an open file.
>
> **LOCK_EX** Place an *exclusive lock*. Only one process may hold an
> exclusive lock for a given    file at a given time.

However, you'd need to open your file with [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), instead of `fopen()`.

Question with abstract example: [flock(): removing locked file without race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708885/flock-removing-locked-file-without-race-condition) Or check this [example](http://tzutalin.blogspot.com/2017/05/flock-cc-sample-code.html).

IMPORTANT: As @JonathanLeffler commented "Note the term "advisory lock" — that means that if the writing process does not test for the lock, it will be able to write. On POSIX-like systems, you can use `flock()` or `lockf()` or `fcntl()` locking on the file descriptor via `fileno(fp)`".

Comment: Note the term "advisory lock" — that means that if the writing process does not test for the lock, it will be able to write.  On POSIX-like systems, you can use `flock()` or `lockf()` or `fcntl()` locking on the file descriptor via `fileno(fp)`.

Comment: If I `open()` then `flock()`, how would I implement the reading functionality that I have since I don't have `getLine()`?

Comment: @NicholasAdamou: if you use file descriptors (`open()`), then you use `read()` and `write()` as your primary I/O interfaces (and `close()` to finish up), though there are a plethora of alternatives for various special I/O purposes.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou that's the easy part, there are a plethora of examples out there doing that. Notice what Jonathan mentioned in his first comment though, it's very important.